# Using storyboard not XIB files anymore

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

**ANOTHER PROBLEM:**

Even with this code: I still get the error of

"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SliderGaloreViewController *sliderGaloreViewController = [[SliderGaloreViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = sliderGaloreViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

I decided to use a storyboard rather than many XIB files now, and I have two pieces of code giving me SIGABRT errors. Could you have a look at them and indicate how to fix the errors. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:
By the way, the error is:**
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SliderGaloreViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

**Cause 1 (in appdelegate):**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([prefs objectForKey:@"PuzzlePicture"] == nil) {
    [prefs setBool:FALSE forKey:@"Refresh"];
    [prefs setInteger:0 forKey:@"PuzzlePicture"];
    [prefs setBool:TRUE forKey:@"CountMoves"];
    //[prefs setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Timer"];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"PuzzleLayoutX"];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"PuzzleLayoutY"];
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SliderGaloreViewController *sliderGaloreViewController = [[SliderGaloreViewController   alloc] initWithNibName:@"SliderGaloreViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = sliderGaloreViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**Cause 2 (in Viewcontroller.m):**

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{
SliderGaloreFlipsideViewController *controller = [[SliderGaloreFlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SliderGaloreFlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`initWithNibName` is not used in storyboard anymore, forget completely about nibs.

`SliderGaloreFlipsideView` is the indentifier meaning the `storyboardId` you give when designing in XCode/

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([prefs objectForKey:@"PuzzlePicture"] == nil) {
    [prefs setBool:FALSE forKey:@"Refresh"];
    [prefs setInteger:0 forKey:@"PuzzlePicture"];
    [prefs setBool:TRUE forKey:@"CountMoves"];
    //[prefs setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Timer"];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"PuzzleLayoutX"];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"PuzzleLayoutY"];
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

SliderGaloreFlipsideViewController *sliderGaloreViewController = 
(SliderGaloreFlipsideViewController *)[storyboard 
      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderGaloreFlipsideView"];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:sliderGaloreViewController 
                                             animated:NO 
                                           completion:nil];

return YES;
}
```

---

If you were trying to set the root controller, then you remove all the code and just set it in the storyboard:

[image]